# How to test json formated actions in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, minitest

I'm trying to test a rails app where all my actions return json formated data. For example, inside `UsersController`

```
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created }
      else
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I use that action from javascript with ajax and works perfectly. Now I try to test that action with this piece of code

```
  test "should create user" do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
      post "/users.json", user: { email: @user.email, name: @user.name }
    end       
  end
```

That throws

> 1) Error: UsersControllerTest#test_should_create_user:
>   ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches
>   {:action=>"/users.json", :controller=>"users",
>   :user=>{:email=>"MyString", :name=>"MyString"}}
>       test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:16:in 'block (2 levels) in '
>       test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:15:in 'block in '

So my question is, How can I test my action that respond to json format? and why the path `/users.json` works perfectly in my app but isn't recognized when I try to test it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can create a JSON request

```
post :create, { user: { email: @user.email, name: @user.name }, format: :json }
```

This is how you can test the response type

RSpec

```
expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
```

MiniTest

```
assert_includes @response['Content-Type'], 'application/json'
```

Comment: Awesome. But I'm using minitest, so do you know how the last part would be with `assert` instead of `expect`?

Comment: Nevermind, the second part with assertion is like this `assert_includes @response["Content-Type"], "application/json"` :)